# can you force apps on the latest android to switch between apns?

Tags: android, apn

We have an app that uses header enrichment to show the users mobile number when registering the app.

My question is we have some users who have custom APNs that are different from the network operator default APNs. Is it possible to force the app to switch APNs? I have heard this may not be possible in the latest android?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Can you turn down the volume?